# how to solve $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n {k\choose2}^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n {k\choose2}^2$$

${k\choose2}={k-1\choose2}+{k-1\choose1},$
${0\choose2}^2+{1\choose2}^2+...+{n-1\choose2}^2+{0\choose1}^2+{1\choose1}^2+...+{n-1\choose1}^2+2\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} {k\choose1}{k\choose2}$
I thought like this, but I'm curious about what to do more here.

Please help me

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: Since ${k\choose 2}^2$ is a 4th-degree polynomial in $k$ with integer values at integers, you can write it as a sum $\sum_{i=0}^4a_i{k\choose i}$ for some coefficients $a_i$; then sums-of-binomials formulas can be used.

Comment: Or you can say it is a degree $5$ polynomial and fit it to the values for $n=0,1,2,3,4,5$ of $ 0   ,0   ,   1  ,      10   ,     46,146$.  Despite all but one of the values being even, it turms out to be an odd function of $n$

Comment: $$\binom n2^2=6\binom{n}4+6\binom n 3 +\binom{n}2$$

Comment: @Henry you need six values for a degree five polynomial.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes -thank you

Comment: You could use the famous identity $$\binom{n}{2}^2=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^3$$ It’s still messy.

Answer (score 4):

Given that
$$
{k\choose 2}^2  = \left(\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)!}{(k-2)! 2!} \right)^2= \frac{(k^2-k)^2}{4} = \frac{k^4}{4} - \frac{k^3}{2} + \frac{k^2}{4} 
$$
So
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} {k\choose 2}^2 &= \frac{1}{4} \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2 -  \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3 + \frac{1}{4} \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^4 \\
&= \frac{1}{24} n (n + 1) (2 n + 1)  -  \frac{1}{8} n^2(n+1)^2 + \frac{1}{120} n (n + 1) (2 n + 1) (3 n^2 + 3 n - 1) \\
& = \frac{1}{120}n (n + 1) \underbrace{\left(10 n +5 - 15n^2 - 15n + 6n^3+6n^2 -2n+3 n^2 + 3 n - 1 \right)}_{\color{blue}{6 n^3 - 6 n^2 - 4 n + 4}}\\
& = \frac{1}{120}n \underbrace{(n + 1)(n-1)}_{\color{purple}{n^2 -1}}(6n^2-4)\\
& =\frac{1}{120}(6n^5-4n^3 - 6n^3+4n)\\
& = \frac{n^5}{20} - \frac{n^3}{12} + \frac{n}{30}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to perform the summation without resorting to Faulhaber's is to define

$$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{k}{2}^2 = \frac{1}{4} \sum_{k=1}^n k^4 - 2k^3 + k^2$$ and then observe

$$\begin{align}
k^5 - (k-1)^5
&= 5k^4 - 10k^3 + 10k^2 - 5k + 1 \\
&= 5(k^4 - 2k^3 + k^2) + 5k^2 - 5k + 1 \\
&= 5 (k^4 - 2k^3 + k^2) + 5k(k-1) + 1. \\
\end{align}$$

Next observe
$$k^3 - (k-1)^3 = 3k^2 - 3k + 1 = 3k(k-1) + 1.$$

Putting this together, we get
$$\begin{align}
k^4 - 2k^3 + k^2 
&= \frac{k^5 - (k-1)^5 - 1}{5} - k(k-1) \\
&= \frac{k^5 - (k-1)^5 - 1}{5} - \frac{k^3 - (k-1)^3 - 1}{3} \\
&= \frac{1}{5} \left( k^5 - (k-1)^5 \right) - \frac{1}{3} \left( k^3 - (k-1)^3 \right) + \frac{2}{15}.
\end{align}$$

Consequently,
$$S_n = \frac{1}{20} \sum_{k=1}^n k^5 - (k-1)^5 - \frac{1}{12} \sum_{k=1}^n k^3 - (k-1)^3 + \frac{n}{30}.$$  Then because each of these sums is telescoping,
$$\begin{align}
S_n &= \frac{n^5}{20} - \frac{n^3}{12} + \frac{n}{30} \\
&= \frac{n}{60}(3n^4 - 5n^2 + 2) \\
&= \frac{n(n-1)(n+1)(3n^2-2)}{60}.
\end{align}$$